# Google translate set select language text one time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i want to set the text of the dropdown select "select language" to "italian", but when the user select the corresponding language, the script work regulary. i found this script that change the "select language" to "translate" but in this case "translate" is permantly, and i don't want this.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({  
      pageLanguage: 'en', 
      layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
    }, 'google_translate_element');
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#google_translate_element').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
      $('.goog-te-menu-value span:first').html('Translate');
      $('.goog-te-menu-frame.skiptranslate').load(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('.goog-te-menu-frame.skiptranslate').contents().find('.goog-te-menu2-item-selected .text').html('Translate');    
        }, 100);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's very unclear what the problem is, and what you want to achieve here..

Comment: sorry for my english, ok, i want modify the string "select language" to italian (default language page) and when the user select the language that he want for example spanish, the string change to "italian" into "spanish" (all with the plugin that work). with this script the string is ever "translate" and i dont want this. http://output.jsbin.com/jucoba this is the script

Comment: Sounds like you want to add a JavaScript event handler when the language is changed, do you know how to do that?

Comment: i'm trying with $('.goog-te-menu2-item').click(function() ... but this not work :(